# C++ compiler "no such file or directory" even with include flag set

Tags: c++, g++, nlohmann-json

I have never used a package manager for C++ packages until today.  I finally got one to semi work, called `cget`.  I'm trying to use a package called `nlohmann/json` and from their documentation I just need to run `cget install nlohmann/json`. The issue is that this puts the include header files in the directory `/cget/include/nlohmann` which (I assume) the g++ compiler doesn't look in for headers.  So I manually moved the `nlohmann` directory into the `/usr/include` directory.  When I compile with `g++ test.cpp -o test` it fails with the error "No such file of directory".  I clearly see the file in the include path, so what am I missing?

```
// test.cpp

#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>
```

I've tried using the Include flag `g++ -I /usr/include test.cpp -o test` and it still fails.

The path to the json.hpp file is `/usr/include/nlohmann/json.hpp`

When I run  `` `g++ -print-prog-name=cc1plus` -v `` it gives:

```
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/include/c++/9
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9
 /usr/include/c++/9/backward
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/include
End of search list.
```

What is causing this error to persist?

Comment: Don't modify `/usr/include` manually. That directory is meant to be controlled by the operating system distribution's package manager. Instead give the correct `-I` (include directories to add to the search list) and `-L` (library directories to add to the search list) flags to the compiler invocation.

Comment: Also, haven't you simply forgotten `.hpp` in the `#include`?

Comment: Thank you.  I moved the directory `/usr/include/nlohmann` back into the `/cget/include` directory and changed the -I flag.  It works now, but do you know how to get the `cget` package manager to handle this automatically?  I would prefer the package go straight into `/usr/include` so I dont need the -I flag (And so VSCode get's rid of the error message)

Comment: @user17732522 That was a typo in my question.  I fixed it

Comment: It would be a bad idea if cget also used `/usr/include`, because then there would be two package managers colliding in that directory and sooner or later it would brick your system. You can of course simply use your system's package manager to install the library instead. I am sure nlohmann/json is common in repositories.

Comment: @user17732522 Thanks again.  I was able to search the `apt` repo and only found `nlohmann-json3-dev`.  `apt` is not listed on their documentation as a package manager. They list about 20 managers too.  So I'm not sure if this version is stable, but I will work with it for now.

Comment: @alvrm apt is a package manager, but it doesn't have its own package repository. Linux system package repositories are usually specific to each Linux distribution, while some of them may share a package manager. For example they list Ubuntu at the top of their page. They probably didn't care to list all repositories for which the project is packaged, especially not if they don't package it themselves. You can use a site like e.g. https://repology.org/project/nlohmann-json/badges to see a (probably incomplete) list of Linux distribution repositories for a given project/package.

Comment: @user17732522 That's a good resource.  I see Ubuntu 20.04 but `apt install` doesn't work except for `nlohmann-json3-dev`.  I used `apt-cache search --names-only 'nlohmann'` to find it.  I actually had to remove it because it seems corrupt or not working.  I appreciate your help.  I'll just have to add /cget/include to includes.